# Swift - Delegate not calling method from other class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to change a label's text in another view controller when a button is pressed. Here's how I'm setting up the delegate:

In FirstViewController under `import UIKit`

```
@objc protocol MyDelegate{
    optional func makeScore()
}
```

In FirstViewController under `class FirstViewController: UIViewController`

```
var delegate:MyDelegate?
```

In FirstViewController when a button is pressed

```
delegate?.makeScore!()
```

In SecondViewController (where `makeScore()` is located)

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, MyDelegate
```

The `makeScore()` method in SecondViewController

```
func makeScore() {
    println("worked")
}
```

It's not logging anything when the button is pressed. I'm pretty sure I set up delegates and protocols correctly. Do you see anything missing?

Note: `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` are not connected by segues. They are both in a `scrollView`.

Comment: Where do you assign the `delegate` property?

Comment: Right between my `@IBOutlets` and `viewDidLoad` override.

Comment: That declares the delegate, but you need to assign an instance of `SecondViewController` to it somewhere for that communication to work.

Comment: I'm confused on the viewController's flow here. Are you attempt to push `SecondViewController` on top of `FirstViewController`, and assign the delegate of the `SecondViewControler` to `FirstViewController`? If so, there needs to be some alterations to your delegate declaration

Comment: How and where do I do that?

Comment: `FirstViewController` is a ViewController with a ScrollView in it. `SecondViewController` is a ViewController that is subviewed into that ScrollView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see now you added the second view controller programmatically with the these lines:

```
let vc6 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Second") as! SecondViewController
self.addChildViewController(vc6)
self.scrollView.addSubview(vc6.view)
```

Just add one line, so that it reads like this:

```
let vc6 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Second") as! SecondViewController
self.delegate = vc6
self.addChildViewController(vc6)
self.scrollView.addSubview(vc6.view)
```

**Edit:**
On a side node, I'm sure a delegate is actually the best approach for what you're trying to do. You'd probably be better off just making a global reference to your `SecondViewController`, then calling on `self.vc6.makeScore()`. Delegates are typically used for calling back to objects that are not contained in the View Controller

Comment: I did it programmatically, but it's not letting me set the delegate. Here's the code I used: `let vc6 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Second") as! SecondViewController`

Comment: How are you adding the second view controller to the scroll view of the first view controller? Is it via storyboard or are you doing it programmatically?

Comment: I'm doing it programmatically: `self.addChildViewController(vc6)` and `self.scrollView.addSubview(vc6.view)`

Comment: Oh I read your code wrong, you actually need to do `self.delegate = vc6`

Comment: It's working now! A couple hours of looking up and that was all I had to add

Comment: Awesome! Just updated my answer to reflect the change.